# How to examine parentNode classList in an if else statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, parent-node

I have a function which is called whenever a checkbox is clicked from a particular group.
I am trying to add a class to the input's parent wrapper when the checkbox is checked, and then remove the class when it isn't checked.
My problem is, I can't seem to get parentNode and classList working together.

eg.  This code works:

```
$(this.parentNode).css( "border", "3px solid red" );
```

But this code returns an undefined error

```
alert($(this.parentNode).classList
```

For context, here's what I'm eventually trying to get to:

```
    if ($(this.parentNode.parentNode).find('.form-type-checkbox').classList.contains("chkbox-checked")) {
      $(this.parentNode.parentNode).find('.form-type-checkbox').removeClass("chkbox-checked");
    } else {
      $(this.parentNode).addClass("chkbox-checked");
    }
```

Comment: `classList` is not a jquery function it is on the native js element - you are mixing up jquery and native js.  Use `.hasClass()` instead: https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest solution could be like you should use toogleClass() of jQuery. Kindly refer the following code.

```
$("#id_of_radioButton").click(function(){
  $("#id_of_parentNode").toggleClass("classname");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(this.parentNode)` is a jQuery object, as `classList` is pure JS property, this will not work on jQuery referenced object.

Try using jQuery's [`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
$(this.parentNode).attr('class');
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't blindly use jQuery for everything. `this.parentNode.classList` will be defined because it's not wrapped in jQuery, since `classList` doesn't exist in jQuery.